# Pandas fillna with method=None (default value) raises an error

Tags: python, pandas, function, merge, nonetype

I am writing a function to aid DataFrame merges between two tables. The function creates a mapping key in the first DataFrame using variables in the second DataFrame.

My issue arises when I try to include the .fillna(method=) at the end of the function.

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd

# Create data
data_1 = {"col_1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "col_2": [1, , 3, , 5]}
data_2 = {"col_1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "col_3": [1, , 3, , 5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)

def merge_on_key(df, df2, join_how="left", fill_na=None):
    # Import libraries
    import pandas as pd

    # Code to create mapping key not required for question

    # Merge the two dataframes
    print(fill_na)
    print(type(fill_na))
    df3 = pd.merge(df, df1, how=join_how, on="col_1").fillna(method=fill_na)

    return df3

df3 = merge_on_key(df, df2)

output:
>>> None
>>> <class 'NoneType'>

error message:
ValueError: Must specify a fill 'value' or 'method'
```

My question is why does the fill_na, which is equal to None, not allow the fillna(method=None, the default value for fillna(method))?

Comment: Some functions are intended not to work with default parameters. You may have to provide something as a method, or a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to either use a **'value'** or a **'method'**. In your call to `fillna` you are setting both of them to `None`. In short, **you're telling Python to fill empty (`None`) values in the dataframe with `None`**, which does nothing and thus it raises an exception.

Based on the docs ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)), you could either assign a non-empty value:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df, df1, how=join_how, on="col_1").fillna(value=0, method=fill_na)
```

or change the method from `None` (which means "directly substitute the `None` values in the dataframe by the given `value`) to one of `{'backfill', 'bfill', 'pad', 'ffill'}` (each documented in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)):

```
df3 = pd.merge(df, df1, how=join_how, on="col_1").fillna( method='backfill')
```

Comment: This is fair. Unfortunately, I don't want to fill values with a default just in case of some corner cases. Thank you!